# Is the practice of keeping written papers or presentations for delivering lectures recommended?

Tags: teaching, professorship, lecture-teaching-method

Professors of my institution use PowerPoint presentations or written papers or some other aid material for delivering a lecture in the classroom.

But doesn't it indicate less expertise?

I have this doubt because it will be easy for an expert professor or well-prepared professor to handle a class of a couple of hours with his preplan instead of using some reference material.

Comment: I'm confused how this could indicate less expertise: would you prefer a professor to ramble with no visual aids whatsoever?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a big fan of power point, but then, I'm not a big fan of lecture in general. But others are fine with it. It has become common practice for many.

It gives the professor a way to think about the lecture, and the course, as a whole so that they are assure that (a) no essential points are missed and (b) that misstatements don't accidentally confuse students or mislead them.

But no, it doesn't imply less expertise. For some, though, it might imply less comfort with speaking in public generally or, at least, extemporaneously.

There are some famous examples of professors getting off track in lectures and, for example, forgetting essential steps in a math proof. But that need not mean less expertise, but just distraction caused by other thoughts intervening.

I usually encourage professors who want to use powerpoint (and can't be convinced otherwise), to distribute the decks in advance.

Comment: +1 Always keep in mind that professors are experts in their topics. They are not necessarily experts in presenting those topics in the optimal educational fashion. Any help they might need with respect to pedagogical things tells you nothing about their expertise on the topics of the class. I can ramble on expertly about my favorite topics incessantly for hours and hours, but if you want me to teach you as much as possible about a certain subject within the limited time of a lecture, I need my notes, so that I know what to tell you and how, and what to leave out.

Comment: Slides are also a way to include material that one just can't do on the board: graphics, videos, music, pictures.

Comment: "getting off track in lectures" a pastor once told me how he suddenly got stuck in the middle of the christmas sermon at the nth of his villages and did not know whether he had said there already what he was going to say or whether this "I know I said it" feeling was from the sermons before...

Answer (score 1):

My evaluation of PowerPoint is that it seems to be intended to make presentations as boring as possible. Every slide with a title, all the same font, all the same format, bullet point text, etc. and etc. It's more suited to presentations of accounting stats than anything else.

But generally, I like prepped slides of some sort for any kind of presentation. When I do lectures though, I also keep written notes. Usually the notes have extra stuff that is not necessarily in the slides. Extra details, extra explanation, answers to predictable questions, bibliographic notes, etc. etc. And I nearly always prep with the idea that these extra notes can be handed out, at least to the "keeners" in the audience.

On the other hand, I do have fond memories of the prof who taught me quantum mechanics in the 4th year of my BSc. He would put his notes down on the table at the front of the room, and turn to the board and start. He could fill 8 very big blackboards with equations, by hand, in impossibly neat script, from memory, in 45 minutes. While explaining the material "over his shoulder" in great and clear detail. We joked we needed water cooled pens to keep up with him. I can still remember when we were doing the ground state of the Helium atom. The class had those up-down chalk boards. And he pulled the board down on the left to erase board-full number 1 to start writing number 5. And EVERYBODY in the class shrieked "NOT YET! NOT YET!" because they were still copying board number 1.

That's a prof who knows his material.

There is probably no "one size fits all" solution here. Not everybody is the kind of person who can do that. I do suggest that PowerPoint needs to have a lot of support to be anything other than a sleeping pill. But prepped slides are probably required for most people.

Comment: My quantum mechanics lecturer was exactly the same!

Comment: I was going to suggest that, rather then erasing board 1 to make room for board 5, your quantum mechanics professor could have provided you with a superposition of both boards. But then, reflecting on the resulting entanglement between everybody's notes, I realized that your desire to copy board 1 indicated that you hadn't really made your peace with the no-cloning theorem.

Answer (score 1):

If I am delivering a lecture just once, then I might use slides (but never PowerPoint) to show in pictures what I could never say in words.

If, however, I am giving  a course that
 1. I shall give again, maybe many times
 2. includes complicated algebraic derivations that the students need to think about,
then there is a case for some kind of handout that they can keep and I can use to make sure I cover everything that I wish to cover.

But far more important than these considerations is to hold the attention of your audience. You will not do that with formulaic PP presentations any more than you would reading without slides from a prepared text. Given that you are human then you must engage the human beings in your audience. PP or not is a secondary issue.